# Ошибка после преобразования void* -> struct*

Tags: c, struct

После преобразования завершается программа. Не пойму в чем может быть причина. Присваиваю в void* тип структуры Recipe*. 
Структура:

```
typedef  struct Recipe{
    char *title;
    ...
}Recipe;
```

Структура "колекция" (связной список):

```
typedef struct data{
    int count;
    void *contained_data;
    struct data * next;
} data;
```

Функция вывода списка:

```
void print_recipes(data* recipes){
    data *start = recipes;

    for (;start != NULL; start = start -> next){
        Recipe *printRecipe = (Recipe*)start -> contained_data;
        char *text = printRecipe -> title; <- получаю вылет в этой строке.
        printf("title - %s\n", text);
    }
}
```

Comment: А у вас тут `start -> contained_data` точно лежит указатель на `Recipe`?

Comment: Скорее всего в момент вылета `printRecipe = 0`. Проверьте отладчиком.

Comment: Вылет на операции разыменования указателя в 99% случаях означает, что указатель не инициализирован

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, вы правы. Спасибо за помощь. Извините за безграмотность=)